# Importing Twitter in Python IDLE

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using Windows 7

Here is what I've done:

```
Start -> run -> cmd ->  cd Python27

pip install twitter_python
pip install twitter_api
pip install twitter_oauth
pip install twitter
```

Everything's getting successfully installed. However on IDLE, I'm getting the following:

```
>>> import twitter

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import twitter
ImportError: No module named twitter
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: strange. for me, pip install twitter_python failed. but twitter_api worked. and after that, import twitter worked in IDLE. also on win7, python 2.7.6. do you have other version of python as well? maybe try using pip in the C:/Python27/Scripts to make sure the python version...

Comment: Just one version. Stuck!

Comment: how about C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages? do you see folder called twitter or egg file etc? otherwise no idea...